# Display images in grid on Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, variables, grid

How do I display images inside the grid this code creates?

I tried to create a var image = document.getElementById() with no success. I can't add the images inside the same var (*var bailanta*) as it only display the link as plain text.

I want to have a mix of both images and text in the grid, and keep the random aspect about it.

```
window.onload = initAll;
var usedSongs = new Array(62);

var bailanta = [{"id": 0, "cancion": 'A'}, 
               ...
                {"id": 64, "cancion": 'Z'},
                ];


function initAll() {
  if (document.getElementById) {
    for (var i=0; i<12; i++) {
      anotherCard(i);
      newCard(i);
    }
  }
  else{
    alert("Your browser does not support this script.");
  }
}

function newCard(table) {
  var numArray = [];
  for(var i=0 ; i<12 ; i++){
    numArray.push(i);  
  } 
  
  for(var j=0 ; j<12 ; j++){
    setSquare(j, table);
  }

}

function setSquare(thisSquare, table){
  var currentSquare = "table" + table + "square" + thisSquare;
  var colPlace = new Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
  var estiloIndex = colPlace[thisSquare];



    do {
      newSong = getNewSong(estiloIndex);
    } while(usedSongs[newSong.id]);
    
    usedSongs[newSong.id] = true;
    document.getElementById(currentSquare).innerHTML = newSong.cancion;    
  }

function getNewSong(estiloIndex) {
  var estiloArray = [];
  switch(estiloIndex) {
    case 0:
      estiloArray = bailanta;
      break;
  }

  var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * estiloArray.length);
  return estiloArray[randomIndex];  
}

function anotherCard(table) {
  for (var i = 1; i < usedSongs.length; i++) {
    usedSongs[i] = false;
  };

  for (var i=0; i<12; i++) {
    document.getElementById("table" + table + "square" + i).className = "";
  }
}

function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex ;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}
```

Comment: You should be able to add them to the same array but you'd need to differentiate between text/image and alter the HTML accordingly.

Comment: Hi Nathan, thanks for your reply! Please could you detail how to differentiate between text/image and what to alter in the HTML? Cheers!

Comment: Well, you could add another field to your array such as "type" of html or image.  Alternatively something could check where you store the text for a valid URI, forward slashes, etc.